# Oxyplot set XAsis increasing by 0.5

Tags: c#, oxyplot

I can't manage to set the xAxis properly I would like interval increasing by 0.5:

```
|--|----|---|
0  0.5  1  1.5  and so on
```

I use this:

```
PositionModel.Axes.Add(new CategoryAxis { 
    Position = AxisPosition.Bottom, Minimum = 9,
    Maximum = 28,
    Key = "XAsis", 
    MajorStep = 1, // useless ?
    MinorStep = 0.5  // useless ?
});
```

But this code doesn't produce the desired result (increasing by 1 instead).

Besides I don't really know what exactly Marjor/MinorStep is.

Documentation is really really light... unfortunatly

**PS: I am really upset to see negative vote without explanation**

Comment: Please tell me why negative vote, I will update my message accordingly

Comment: Its bad that your question got downvoted, but to answer your question: I don't think you need to explicitly mention the `interval`. Just start plotting the values and Oxyplot will automatically do it for you. `MajorStep` is the maximum allowed interval and `MinorStep` is the minimum allowed interval

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `Axis` instead of `CategoryAxis` which provide following two extra properties `LabelField` and `ItemsSource` that enable user to custom axis label; and thus render the `MinorStep` property in `CategoryAxis` useless and **is hard-coded to 1**.

You can still accomplish what you want provided you add  `LabelField/ItemsSouce` properties with proper data, but it is much simpler by using `Axis`.

For reference, have a look at the source code at :
https://github.com/oxyplot/oxyplot/blob/develop/Source/OxyPlot/Axes/CategoryAxis.cs